# Powershell - Cannot parse JSON - Get NotSpecified error

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-5.0

**Code used to try parsing file**

```
$myJson = Get-Content cleantest2.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Get below error when trying to parse JSON file.**

```
$myJson = Get-Content cleantest2.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

**EDIT: As noted, the above error was truncated because it was too long. Here is the full error.**

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (2): {"id":0,"resourcePackage
s":[{"resourcePackage":{"name":"SharedResources","type":2,"i
tems":[{"type":202,"path":"BaseThemes/CY18SU07.json","name"
:"CY18SU07"}],"disabled":false}}],"sections":[{"id":0,"name"
:"ReportSection","displayName":"Page 1","filters":"[]","ord
inal":0,"visualContainers":[{"x":10,"y":0,"z":1,"width":280,
"height":280,"config":"{\"name\":\"5a0b8ef6c97162087ff7\",\
"layouts\":[{\"id\":0,\"position\":{\"x\":10,\"y\":0,\"width
\":280,\"height\":280,\"z\":1}}],\"singleVisual\":{\"visual
Type\":\"tableEx\",\"projections\":{\"Values\":[{\"queryRef\
":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"queryRef\":\"se
rvers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"queryRef\":\"servers_a
nd_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"prototypeQuery\":{\"Version\":
2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"s\",\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applica
tions\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"Source
Ref\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"App
Name\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"
Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},
\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applicati
ons.Cust_Nme\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{
\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"},\"Name\":\"serve
rs_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"drillFilterOtherVisuals\":t
rue}}","filters":"[]","query":"{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQu
eryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\
"Name\":\"s\",\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}],\"S
elect\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Sourc
e\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"App
Name\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"
Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},
\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applicati
ons.Cust_Nme\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{
\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"},\"Name\":\"serve
rs_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"G
roupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1,2],\"Subtotal\":1}]},\"Da
taReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Window\":{\"C
ount\":500}}},\"Version\":1}}}]}","dataTransforms":"{\"proj
ectionOrdering\":{\"Values\":[0,1,2]},\"queryMetadata\":{\"S
elect\":[{\"Restatement\":\"App
Name\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\",\"Typ
e\":2048},{\"Restatement\":\"Cust_Nme\",\"Name\":\"servers_a
nd_applications.Cust_Nme\",\"Type\":2048},{\"Restatement\":
\"MU_ID\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\",\"Type
\":2048}]},\"visualElements\":[{\"DataRoles\":[{\"Name\":\"
Values\",\"Projection\":0,\"isActive\":false},{\"Name\":\"Va
lues\",\"Projection\":1,\"isActive\":false},{\"Name\":\"Val
ues\",\"Projection\":2,\"isActive\":false}]}],\"selects\":[{
\"displayName\":\"App
Name\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\",
\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"un
derlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"S
ourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Prop
erty\":\"App Name\"}}},{\"displayName\":\"Cust_Nme\",\"quer
yName\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\",\"roles\":{\"V
alues\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\
":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"
Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust
_Nme\"}}},{\"displayName\":\"MU_ID\",\"queryName\":\"servers
_and_applications.MU_ID\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"typ
e\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Col
umn\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_
and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"}}}]}"}],"config"
:"{}","displayOption":1,"width":1280,"height":720}],"config
":"{\"version\":\"3.19\",\"themeCollection\":{\"baseTheme\":
{\"name\":\"CY18SU07\",\"version\":\"3.22\",\"type\":2}},\"
activeSectionIndex\":0,\"defaultDrillFilterOtherVisuals\":tr
ue,\"settings\":{\"useStylableVisualContainerHeader\":true,
\"exportDataMode\":1}}","layoutOptimization":0}
At line:1 char:46
+ $myJson = Get-Content cleantest2.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

**Below is file that was trying to get parsed.**

```
{"id":0,"resourcePackages":[{"resourcePackage":{"name":"SharedResources","type":2,"items":[{"type":202,"path":"BaseThemes/CY18SU07.json","name":"CY18SU07"}],"disabled":false}}],"sections":[{"id":0,"name":"ReportSection","displayName":"Page 1","filters":"[]","ordinal":0,"visualContainers":[{"x":10,"y":0,"z":1,"width":280,"height":280,"config":"{\"name\":\"5a0b8ef6c97162087ff7\",\"layouts\":[{\"id\":0,\"position\":{\"x\":10,\"y\":0,\"width\":280,\"height\":280,\"z\":1}}],\"singleVisual\":{\"visualType\":\"tableEx\",\"projections\":{\"Values\":[{\"queryRef\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"queryRef\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"queryRef\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"prototypeQuery\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"s\",\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"App Name\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"drillFilterOtherVisuals\":true}}","filters":"[]","query":"{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"s\",\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"App Name\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1,2],\"Subtotal\":1}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Window\":{\"Count\":500}}},\"Version\":1}}}]}","dataTransforms":"{\"projectionOrdering\":{\"Values\":[0,1,2]},\"queryMetadata\":{\"Select\":[{\"Restatement\":\"App Name\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\",\"Type\":2048},{\"Restatement\":\"Cust_Nme\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\",\"Type\":2048},{\"Restatement\":\"MU_ID\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\",\"Type\":2048}]},\"visualElements\":[{\"DataRoles\":[{\"Name\":\"Values\",\"Projection\":0,\"isActive\":false},{\"Name\":\"Values\",\"Projection\":1,\"isActive\":false},{\"Name\":\"Values\",\"Projection\":2,\"isActive\":false}]}],\"selects\":[{\"displayName\":\"App Name\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"App Name\"}}},{\"displayName\":\"Cust_Nme\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"}}},{\"displayName\":\"MU_ID\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"}}}]}"}],"config":"{}","displayOption":1,"width":1280,"height":720}],"config":"{\"version\":\"3.19\",\"themeCollection\":{\"baseTheme\":{\"name\":\"CY18SU07\",\"version\":\"3.22\",\"type\":2}},\"activeSectionIndex\":0,\"defaultDrillFilterOtherVisuals\":true,\"settings\":{\"useStylableVisualContainerHeader\":true,\"exportDataMode\":1}}","layoutOptimization":0}
```

Reformatted:

```
{
    "id":  0,
    "resourcePackages":  [
                             {
                                 "resourcePackage":  {
                                                         "name":  "SharedResources",
                                                         "type":  2,
                                                         "items":  [
                                                                       {
                                                                           "type":  202,
                                                                           "path":  "BaseThemes/CY18SU07.json",
                                                                           "name":  "CY18SU07"
                                                                       }
                                                                   ],
                                                         "disabled":  false
                                                     }
                             }
                         ],
    "sections":  [
                     {
                         "id":  0,
                         "name":  "ReportSection",
                         "displayName":  "Page 1",
                         "filters":  "[]",
                         "ordinal":  0,
                         "visualContainers":  [
                                                  {
                                                      "x":  10,
                                                      "y":  0,
                                                      "z":  1,
                                                      "width":  280,
                                                      "height":  280,
                                                      "config":  "{\"name\":\"5a0b8ef6c97162087ff7\",\"layouts\":[{\"id\":0,\"position\":{\"x\":10,\"y\":0,\"width\":280,\"height\":280,\"z\":1}}],\"singleVisual\":{\"visualType\":\"tableEx\",\"projections\":{\"Values\":[{\"queryRef\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"queryRef\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"queryRef\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"prototypeQuery\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"s\",\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"App Name\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"drillFilterOtherVisuals\":true}}",
                                                      "filters":  "[]",
                                                      "query":  "{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"s\",\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"App Name\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"s\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"},\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\"}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1,2],\"Subtotal\":1}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Window\":{\"Count\":500}}},\"Version\":1}}}]}",
                                                      "dataTransforms":  "{\"projectionOrdering\":{\"Values\":[0,1,2]},\"queryMetadata\":{\"Select\":[{\"Restatement\":\"App Name\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\",\"Type\":2048},{\"Restatement\":\"Cust_Nme\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\",\"Type\":2048},{\"Restatement\":\"MU_ID\",\"Name\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\",\"Type\":2048}]},\"visualElements\":[{\"DataRoles\":[{\"Name\":\"Values\",\"Projection\":0,\"isActive\":false},{\"Name\":\"Values\",\"Projection\":1,\"isActive\":false},{\"Name\":\"Values\",\"Projection\":2,\"isActive\":false}]}],\"selects\":[{\"displayName\":\"App Name\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.App Name\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"App Name\"}}},{\"displayName\":\"Cust_Nme\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.Cust_Nme\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"Cust_Nme\"}}},{\"displayName\":\"MU_ID\",\"queryName\":\"servers_and_applications.MU_ID\",\"roles\":{\"Values\":true},\"type\":{\"category\":null,\"underlyingType\":1},\"expr\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Entity\":\"servers_and_applications\"}},\"Property\":\"MU_ID\"}}}]}"
                                                  }
                                              ],
                         "config":  "{}",
                         "displayOption":  1,
                         "width":  1280,
                         "height":  720
                     }
                 ],
    "config":  "{\"version\":\"3.19\",\"themeCollection\":{\"baseTheme\":{\"name\":\"CY18SU07\",\"version\":\"3.22\",\"type\":2}},\"activeSectionIndex\":0,\"defaultDrillFilterOtherVisuals\":true,\"settings\":{\"useStylableVisualContainerHeader\":true,\"exportDataMode\":1}}",
    "layoutOptimization":  0
}
```

**Items attempted:**

- Used online formator on text and then re-ran command on resulting string. - Worked
- Tried to import raw string and export as JSON using ConverTo-Json method but didn't work correctly.
- Tried parsing using Python but had similar issue.

Comment: Check file encoding as assigning the string to a variable `$Json = '"id":0, ... '; $Json | ConvertFrom-Json` works fine.

Comment: You're not showing a part of the error message, namely the specific part that points out in what way the JSON is considered malformed.

Comment: There sure is a lot of backslashes.  But it works for me.

Comment: I don't see any non-ascii characters.  Watch out for convertto-json's default depth of 2.

Comment: The JSON-structure it self has no issues.

Comment: I added a reformatted version of the json.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem.  I save the text to a file and run convertFrom-json and there is no error.  Then I run convertTo-json and again no error and it outputs the json.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the encoding to unicode. See below sample execution.

```
$myJson = Get-Content cleantest2.json -Encoding unicode | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74707381/45375) implies that **your input file, `cleantest2.json`, was *malformed***:

- The fact that `-Encoding Unicode` solved your problem implies that the file is a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)LE-encoded file that *lacks a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)*, which means that it provides no indication to readers of the file what its encoding is, and causes [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to (justifiably) *misinterpret* the file.
- Consider correcting the problem at the source: make the creator of file `cleantest2.json` create it *with* the appropriate BOM, the way that `Set-Content -Encoding Unicode` does, for instance.

---

As for **troubleshooting** your symptom:

If a string's *display output* is *seemingly* correct, but *processing* of the string doesn't work as expected, the cause is usually the **presence of *hidden control characters***.

Specifically, **misreading a BOM-less UTF16-LE ("Unicode") file** as either ANSI-encoded (which *Windows PowerShell* does by default) or UTF-8 (as *PowerShell (Core) 7+* does by default) **results in all ASCII-range characters being followed by a `NUL` character (code point `0x0`)each**, and these `NUL` characters are **invisible** when you *print* the string.

For testing, you can **create a malformed UTF-16LE file as follows**:

```bash
# Write 'foo' with UTF-16LE encoding to file 'cleantest2.json' *without a BOM*:
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$PWD/cleantest2.json", "f`0o`0`o`0")
```

A **simple test for the presence of at least one `NUL` character** (expressed as `` "`0" `` in PowerShell) is:

```bash
(Get-Content cleantest2.json -Raw) -match "`0"  # "`0" creates a NUL
```

**Piping to [`Format-Hex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex)** can also help in *this* case:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
# Look for `00` values.
Get-Content cleantest2.json -Raw | Format-Hex
```

The **`Debug-String` helper function**, available from [this MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1) offers a **direct visualization**:

```bash
# Download and define the Debug-String function.
# NOTE: 
#  I can personally assure you that doing this is safe, but you
#  you should always check the source code first.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1/raw/Debug-String.ps1 | iex

Get-Content cleantest2.json -Raw | Debug-String
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

---

A note re **spotting the problem with the help of *text editors***:

- This may not help, because many editors correctly detect UTF-16LE files even *without a BOM* (e.g., Notepad, Visual Studio Code), and in their status bar report just "UTF-16 LE" *whether or not a BOM is present*.
- However, **if an editor offers a *hex* view** (of the bytes that make up the file), you'll be able to tell: If an UTF-16LE file ***does* have a BOM**, the **first two bytes are `FF FE`** (for UTF-8 files that have a BOM, the first *three* bytes are `EF BB BF`).

  - Visual Studio Code has a [Hex Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor) extension
  - js2010 reports that Emacs has a hexl-mode.

---

<sup>[1] Use of `Format-Hex` to discover *(non-ASCII-range) Unicode characters* isn't an option in *Windows PowerShell*, because it represents any non-ASCII chars. as `3f`, i.e. literal `?`. In *PowerShell (Core)* it shows the ASCII rendering of *the individual bytes that make up the UTF-8 encoding* of non-ASCII characters, which can be confusing.</sup>

Comment: Confusingly, It looks alright sending get-content to the console.  Windows Notepad can actually handle this type of file, since it happens with some windows utilities.  convertfrom-json gave the same invalid object passed in error.

Comment: Emacs has a hexl-mode which is good for this as well.

Comment: @js2010, please see my  update (new bottom section).